# How to quit emacs bottom buffer in magit mode

Tags: emacs

When using magit in emacs, I have problem with this bottom buffer, which list some options and commands for magit. My questions:

1. How can i apply a selected options. for example:

```
    -n Limit number of commits (-n)
     -A Limit to author (--author=)
```

when moved to the first "-n Limit" and enter, it will add a new empty line(it is editable buffer).

2. How can I quit this buffer. `c-x k` results:

   Window #<window 159 on VerificationManager.js> has same side left as window #<window 9 on  *Treemacs-Scoped-Buffer-#<frame  *Minibuf-1* - emacs@shijiexu-home 0x559d2de6b480>*> but no common parent

I am also unabel to adjust its height using mouse as this buffer takes up too large screen size.

[image]

Comment: To apply `-n`, just type `-n`. `\C-g` should exit the window (pretty standard Emacs thing).